# Speeding up a falling image every 5 seconds by +0.1 speed

Tags: objective-c

Just a fast question ;)

my speed of the falling images is:

```
int speed = 5; // pixel per update (i.e. 60 updates/second = 60 pixels/second)
```

how do i add + 0.01 speed every 5 seconds?

Comment: With `NSTimer` and Google.

Comment: Are you hiring me to write your code?

Comment: Can you demonstrate some amount of effort?

Comment: heres my NSTimer:                                                            _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: If you're posting an answer, it should be posted as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: it not an answer its my NSTimer.. i need to add speed every second, but don´t know how...

Comment: By the way, you want to change that integer to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have declared speed as an integer, you will not be able to add 0.01 to it. First you must declare speed as a float. Second, you must set up an NSTimer as shown below:

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then you must write a function to perform whatever it is you want to perform 60 times per second.

```
- (void)timerLoop {
    // Add 0.01 to speed every time the function is called.
    speed += 0.01;
}
```

Be careful though, since the resolution of NSTimer is not high enough to execute exactly every 1/60th of a second. This may cause frame rate issues if you are trying to do this for a game loop. This is how I originally handled updating position and velocity in my iOS game SlothDrop (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slothdrop-free/id789603341?mt=8&uo=4). I later went on to use CADisplayLink.